# How to prove that the shortest path between two points in sphere is a part of the great circle?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, 3d

It is a known fact that the shortest path between tow points in sphere is a part of the great circle. but I don't know the proof of this claim so I tried to **rigorously** prove it myself.

My attempt: Claim 1 Let two points $a,b$ be in the opposite poles of the sphere with radius $r$ assume the distance is less than $\pi r$ by the symmetry of the sphere any two points in the opposite side of the sphere must have their distance less than $\pi r$  i.e the radius  is less than $r$ which contradicts the hypothesis (I am not sure this part is correct).

> Claim: any two points can be part of a Great circle.

Let two points $a,b$ be in the opposite poles and let $c$ be  in the middle of distance between them in the great sphere if the distance between $c,a$ is less than half of distance in the great sphere then by the symmetry of the sphere the distance between $c,b$ which contradicts Claim 1.

the second method can be generalised for all rational numbers but I am having a trouble generalising this claim for irrationals

I am sure there is a simple **rigorous** proof of this fact but I can't find it.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to prove. Do you want to prove any two points belong on a great circle, or do you want to prove great circle is the shortest path, or both?

Comment: For the first one, just draw the plane containing $a$, $b$ and $O$. This plane cuts a cross-section of the sphere, which is a great circle. For the second one, I don't know a rigorous proof using precalculus...

Comment: @DS you can use more advanced mathematics.

Comment: What is the question though? And there are two duplicates in the related section.

Comment: The proof on [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle#Derivation_of_shortest_paths) is fine.

Comment: For an intuitive argument, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1818572/1088689) answer

Comment: @DS btw hat is calculus of variations ? is it something different than calculus ? is it pure math ?

Comment: I'm not someone knowledgeable in calculus, but intuitively: Like you use calculus to find extrema over $\Bbb R$ (or its intervals), calculus of variations is used to find extrema over other things like constraining functions, surfaces, etc.

Comment: @pie: Please refer to textbooks on differential geometry on the topic of  geodesics of a sphere/surfaces of revolution.

Answer (score 3):

First, I'll define the following unit vectors:

$u_0 = \dfrac{b - a}{\| b - a\|}$

$u_1 = \dfrac{a + b}{\| a + b \| }$

$u_2 = \dfrac{a \times b }{ \| a \times b \| }$

then the axis of rotation that takes $a$ to $b$ is given by

$ U = \cos \alpha \ u_1 + \sin \alpha \ u_2 $

unit vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ are orthogonal to $U$, where

$ v_1 = \sin \alpha \ u_1 - \cos \alpha \ u_2 $

$ v_2 = u_0 $

Now vector $a$ can written in the basis $ u_0 , u_1 , u_2 $ as

$ a = r( - \sin \phi \ u_0 + \cos \phi  \ u_1) $

$ b =  r( \sin \phi \ u_0 + \cos \phi \ u_1) $

where $ 2 \phi $ is the angle between $a $ and $ b$ .

The projection of $a$ onto $v_1$ is

$ a_1 = ( a \cdot v_1 ) v_1 = r (\sin \alpha \cos \phi)  v_1 $

and onto $v_2$ is

$ a_2 = (a \cdot v_2 ) v_2 = r ( - \sin \phi ) v_2  $

Similarly, the projections of $ b$ onto $v_1$ and $v_2$ are

$ b_1 = r (\sin \alpha \cos \phi) v_1 $

$ b_2 = r \sin \phi v_2 $

Therefore, the angle of rotation is given by

$ \psi = 2 \tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{ \sin \phi }{ \sin \alpha \cos \phi } \right) = 2 \tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{\tan \phi }{ \sin \alpha } \right) $

The length of the projection of $a$ onto the plane containing $v_1 $ and $v_2$ is

$ \| \text{Proj}(a) \| = \| \text{Proj}(b) \| = r \sqrt{\sin^2 \alpha \cos^2 \phi + \sin^2 \phi} $

Therefore, the distance travelled in rotating from $a$ to $b$ is

$ s(\alpha) = 2 r \sqrt{\sin^2 \alpha \cos^2 \phi + \sin^2 \phi} \tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{\tan \phi }{ \sin \alpha } \right) $

Note that $ s(0) = \displaystyle \lim_{\alpha \to 0+} s(\alpha) = r \
\pi \sin(\phi) $, while $s(\dfrac{\pi}{2}) = 2 r \phi $

We can differentiate $s(\alpha)$, but it is going to be involved, so instead, I've plotted the function $s(\alpha)$ over $\alpha \in [0, \pi]$ for a typical $\phi = \dfrac{\pi}{6} $ and for $ r = 1 $.

This is shown in [this Sage Worksheet](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxljcEKgzAQRO9C_mFu2bUBo4e2l_6KEDxIQIxNpCR_3008elmGebMz2aDgg5-LpLNozaqrxuGJh6fqkugJPdI3noTkd8p9Y-PbMubGlpCo8Dzh0QLl8lmIO91OqEfM4fYuW8cWai8MSOZf1mC0lo10biHKtl6jKxr8Bw3HKqM=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Clearly the minimum (of the arc length) occurs at $\alpha = 90^\circ$.

Hence, the axis that minimizes the arc length is given by

$ U = u_2 $

With this axis, the circular arc resulting from rotating $a$ into $b$ is part of a great circle, whose normal vector (the vector perpendicular to its plane) is $U$.